# Making custom Attributes in Python

Tags: python, list, function, class

I'm new to python so I don't know much.
I was defining a function to work with lists and I want that function to be used like an attribute. For example to sort a list we use: `list.sort()`

Basically, instead of using the function like `function(list)` I want to use it like this: `list.function()`

Comment: For that you can define a class while inherit the inbuilt list class (so that you will be able use all the existing list methods) with methods as additional desired function/behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a class

```
class MyClass():
    def function(self, param):
        print(param)

myClass = MYClass()
myClass.function()
```

You can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a [class](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) that [inherits](https://realpython.com/python-super/) the `list` class.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        
    def all_caps(self):
        return [item.upper() if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in self]
    
mylist = MyList(['hi', 'hello', 1234])

mylist.all_caps()
```

Comment: But I'd have to convert the list to a MyList data type in order to use this, is there any way to just use a list directly?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Is there a particular reason you want this behavior?

Comment: I'm making a function which will work with lists, and I want it to be used like the sort function in which we attribute listname in front of function.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom class that inherit from original list and then using `builtins` module assign new extended class to previous list:

```
import builtins

class my_list(list):
  def f(self):
    return sum(self)

builtins.list = my_list


arr = list([1,2,3])
x = arr.f()
print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

**Warning**

Remember that you need to create every list using `list()` function to make sure your method will work.